# Finding unused files in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've recently started work on a new app which is basically a copy of a previous app I made, with a few changes. To make this new app I've copied the old app and removed some stuff that isn't needed.

I'm wondering, is there any way to tell which class files are being used in Xcode? Or any tips on how to find unused files?

Comment: **dead easy solution** for 2020 ... https://github.com/PaulTaykalo/swift-scripts  https://medium.com/@gabriel_lewis/how-to-easily-find-unused-swift-code-in-xcode-159631961acf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There isn't any functionality like this built into Xcode, but the issue of unused classes/files etc isn't as simple as one may think.

People have created scripts to try and determine unused files. I have used the [script located here](https://github.com/arun80/xcodeutils), which searches through all your source files, and tries to pair up the resource files. The script also tries to check for source files not included within your project.

The reason its not so trivial is that Obj-C is a very dynamic language; a lot of things are determined at run-time. As such, it sometimes can be tricky to figure out unused files statically. For example, an image name might be determined on the fly depending on user input.

I don't know how big your application is, but you could try a dependency graph, and check for orphan classes.

Comment: It would be nice if Xcode had some built in function to do this. The link you posted to that script is very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) IDE from Jetbrains has some very decent code inspection functions. It can point out unused classes and other resources, and claims to be fully Xcode compatible.

Comment: Can you please let me know How Appcode identify unused code ? Any command used for same ?

Comment: AppCode is no longer available as a commercial product as of December 14, 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I've spent much time today to find tool, which helped me a lot a few months ago. Here it is:
https://github.com/peripheryapp/periphery

It can find unused classes, functions, properties etc in Swift code.

P.S. It has more than 3000 stars on the Github. So it is strange that it's not listed here.

Answer (score 1):

Also see this shell scripts http://mfaizanshaikh.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/how-to-remove-unused-images-from-xcode-project/

Basically the shell script below, finds all the `png` files in your project that are not used in any of the `xib` files. Of course if you have used the `png` file in other ways (storyboards, load in the code), this script will still show them as unused.
for reference I paste the scripts here as well:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROJ=`find . -name '*.xib' -o -name '*.[mh]'`

for png in `find . -name '*.png'`
do
    name=`basename $png`
    if ! grep -q $name $PROJ; then
        echo "$png is not referenced"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I apologize for my bluntness, but what does this have to do with the actual question? Did you even read it?

Comment: The last part of the questions asks for any tips on finding unused files. This appears to address finding unused image files. It's not a complete answer to the question but by beginning with "Also see this..." I don't think he intended it to be a complete answer, merely some additional helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called Slender by Martiancraft that is good for suggesting potentially unused images.

http://martiancraft.com/products/slender.html

I believe that Faux Pas does something similar for class files, but I will check. That app does also look for unused methods, translations and resources.

http://fauxpasapp.com/rules/#rule-UnusedResource

I haven't used either app recently, but can remember being impressed with both previously.

Comment: good news, there's now a much easier solution - nothing to install - https://github.com/PaulTaykalo/swift-scripts

Comment: Thanks @Fattie. That'll get us some of the way there, but just seems to find unused Swift functions and variables - not images or other non-Swift files?

Comment: @ siburb you're definitely **correct**, it's only a partial solution.  I actually didn't thik about the **images** aspect and didn't notice you mention them - another good point.  ridiculous there's no all-round convenient solution for this

Comment: Faux pas was fantastic but hasn't been updated since 2017.